# Solve the following recurrence relation. $a_{n+1} - 2a_{n} = 2^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$a_{n+1} - 2a_{n} = 2^n$ $;\ n\geq0\ ;\ a_0 = 1 $

I worked through the above example which was done in a YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfF_XSEX1Sk&t=423s) and managed to reach the answer of:

$a_{n}= 2^n + n2^{n-1}$

Which lines up with the answer achieved in the video.

I believe the answer to be wrong because if you calculate the values for n = 1, 2, 3 and so on the values between the solution and the recurrence relation differ.

Solution:
$a_1 = 3 \ a_2 = 8 \ a_3 = 20$

Recurrence Relation:
$a_1 = 4 \ a_2 = 8 \ a_3 = 24$

Have I made a stupid mistake somewhere, misunderstood something or is the solution really incorrect?
If it is incorrect what is the correct solution and how does one reach it?

Comment: The solution is correct, the recurrence Relation gives $a_1=3$ and not $a_1=4$, I think you replaced n by 1 and not n=0 to find $a_1$.

Comment: @Laassilasouhayl Is right. Since $a_{n+1}=2a_n+2^n$, $a_n=2a_{n-1}+2^{n-1}$, so e.g.$$a_1=2a_0+2^0=2\times1+1=3$$as expected. I'm not sure why you thought the recurrence relation implies $a_2=2a_1$.

Comment: ok I understand now thank you. $n+1$ is referring to the next term which would be $n=1$ therefore $n$ is still referring to $n=0$